# How do I know what my server's name is?

Tags: ftp, server, filezilla, acquia

I've been using Acquia Cloud to host my website, and I'm still having trouble figuring out what the name of my server is.

Under the server tab on my free account, Acquia provides an example of a server name in this format: `ssh site.environment@free-5700.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com`

Since my site name is `st4rgut` and environment is `dev`, I assumed the server name is st4rgut.dev@free-5700.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com

But Filezilla failed to connect the server.  After some Googling of Acquia server names, I came across this format: `srv-4808.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com` Should my server name start with `srv`?

How should I go about finding the server name?  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: No, that's not the server name. The _username_ is `st4grut.dev`, and the server name is `free-5700.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com`.

Answer (score -1):

Your server name is : free-5700.devcloud.hosting.acquia.com

Please try with this name and let me know.